# error in file uploading and inserting data into php myadmin

Tags: php

I'm getting error in this code. i want to limit file upload sixe to 1.5 mb and type is only doc file...alert prompted first and now only file type alert is prompting and data but is also saving into php myadmin. which includes all types of files i.e. pdf, mp4 etc. which i does not want. anyone have a solution.

Heres the Code:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","physiocon");
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$edit_state = false;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email= $_POST['email'];
 $abscategory = $_POST['abscategory'];
 $submcategory = $_POST['submcategory'];
 $uploadOk = 1;

 $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];

 $target = "admin/submitted abstracts/".basename($_FILES['file'['name']);

  $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    // Check if file already exists
 if (file_exists($target)) {
  echo ("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
  window.alert('Sorry File is already Exists. Please Upload Another File 
  or Rename Your File!');
  window.location.href='abstract_submission.php';
  </script>");
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 1500) {
    echo ("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
  window.alert('Sorry File Size Allowed is upto 1.5 MB !');
  window.location.href='abstract_submission.php';
  </script>");
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }

    // Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "doc") {
    echo ("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
  window.alert('Sorry only .doc file is allowed !');
  window.location.href='abstract_submission.php';
  </script>");
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

$sql="INSERT INTO `abstracts`(`name`, `email`, `abs_file`, `abs_ategory`, 
     `subm_category`) VALUES 
   ('$name','$email','$file','$abscategory','$submcategory')";

mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target)){

 echo ("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
  window.alert('Testimonial Added Successfully !');
  window.location.href='abstract_submission.php';
  </script>");

} else {
  echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($con); 
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are setting a variable $uploadOk but you are never checking it.

Try to stop the execution if that variable is 0. That way no SQL query will be made.

```
......
if($imageFileType != "doc") {
  echo ("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
  window.alert('Sorry only .doc file is allowed !');
  window.location.href='abstract_submission.php';
  </script>");
  $uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($uploadOk === 0) {
  die("Invalid upload");
}
.......
```

Consider using a boolean value (true or false) for $uploadOk variable, not an integer one.

Also, your code is open for sql injection. Do not use $_POST values directly into your SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate file types by checking the extension of uploaded file (by name).

Replace Below code COndition

```
  // Allow certain file formats
 if($imageFileType != "doc"){
    // Your JavaScript code
 }
```

Replace Condition with with

```
$allowedExtsImg=array("doc","docx");
$extensionsub = explode(".", $file);
$extension = strtolower(end($extensionsub));
if (!in_array($extension, $allowedExtsImg))
{
  //Enter your JavaScript code here
}
```

After all validation at end before your code write if condition

```
// This condition will prevent below action if there is a validation error above.
if($uploadOk!=0){
   // Your Insert Query, and Upload file Code
}
```